# Xamarin Drag/Drop labels

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am following this code from someone: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/DragViewSample/tree/master/DragViewSample/DragViewSample to drag/drop labels, so I used this xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Memento.DraggableView"
             x:Class="MyApp.TestPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="dragLayout"
                          AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" IsVisible="true"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <local:DraggableView x:Name="dragView"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                          DragMode="Touch" DragDirection="All" >
                <local:DraggableView.Content>
                    <Label Text="Test Label" TextColor="Black" />
                </local:DraggableView.Content>
            </local:DraggableView>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But when I try to move the label, nothing happens!?
I didn't add any C# code on the background, because I don't think that was neccesary. In his example he only uses c# for a listview, but I removed that, so....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a much simpler layout first to get the drag-and-drop behavior working, then add in the other elements.  Right now you have an incredibly complicated nested layout so it's very difficult to determine what is happening.

Comment: I made the page way easier as you said, but still same result. Code is above...

Comment: Have you added the custom renderer to Android and iOS proj, check [this class](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/DragViewSample/tree/master/DragViewSample/DragViewSample.Android/Renderers)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. Totally missed the renderer!